# Spark infer schema with limit during a read.csv

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to infer a Spark.DataFrame schema from a directory of CSV files using a small subset of the rows (say `limit(100)`).

However, setting `inferSchema` to `True` means that the `Input Size / Records` for the `FileScanRDD` seems to always be equal to the number of rows in all the CSV files.

Is there a way to make the FileScan more selective, such that Spark looks at fewer rows when inferring a schema?

Note: setting the [`samplingRatio` option](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9af946/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVUtils.scala#L104-L107) to be < 1.0 does not have the desired behaviour, though it is clear that inferSchema uses only the sampled subset of rows.

Comment: You can always write two hundreds of lines into a tmp csv file then read that file with schema inference otherwise the csv source will always scan the whole file to infer the schema...

Comment: Right; there are several "out-of-band" approaches that work; was hoping to avoid that. But, thanks @eliasah!

Comment: This might be solved in Spark 3+ https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2d01bccbd4c93bfbfa1a9e618fcb795b7106f01c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3812

Comment: randomly filter data and then store that into a temp file, read back the temp file and then infer the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are only interested in the schema, here is a possible approach based on [cipri.l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915447/cipri-l)'s post in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044419/how-can-i-optimize-schema-inference-on-a-remote-file-for-csv-with-spark/56044537#56044537)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.{CSVOptions, TextInputCSVDataSource}
def inferSchemaFromSample(sparkSession: SparkSession, fileLocation: String, sampleSize: Int, isFirstRowHeader: Boolean): StructType = {
  // Build a Dataset composed of the first sampleSize lines from the input files as plain text strings
  val dataSample: Array[String] = sparkSession.read.textFile(fileLocation).head(sampleSize)
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val sampleDS: Dataset[String] = sparkSession.createDataset(dataSample)
  // Provide information about the CSV files' structure
  val firstLine = dataSample.head
  val extraOptions = Map("inferSchema" -> "true",   "header" -> isFirstRowHeader.toString)
  val csvOptions: CSVOptions = new CSVOptions(extraOptions, sparkSession.sessionState.conf.sessionLocalTimeZone)
  // Infer the CSV schema based on the sample data
  val schema = TextInputCSVDataSource.inferFromDataset(sparkSession, sampleDS, Some(firstLine), csvOptions)
  schema
}
```

Unlike [GMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8968982/gmc)'s answer from above, this approach tries to directly infer the schema the same way the DataFrameReader.csv() does in the background (but without going through the effort of building an additional Dataset with that schema, that we would then only use to retrieve the schema back from it)

The schema is inferred based on a Dataset[String] containing only the first `sampleSize` lines from the input files as plain text strings.

When trying to retrieve samples from data, Spark has only 2 types of methods:

1. Methods that retrieve a given percentage of the data. This operation takes random samples from all partitions. It benefits from higher parallelism, but it must read all the input files.
2. Methods that retrieve a specific number of rows. This operation must collect the data on the driver, but it could read a single partition (if the required row count is low enough)

Since you mentioned you want to use a specific small number of rows and since you want to avoid touching all the data, I provided a solution based on option 2

PS: The DataFrameReader.textFile method accepts paths to files, folders and it also has a varargs variant, so you could pass in one or more files or folders.

Comment: Thanks! Right, there's a common theme here; to avoid reading from all partitions, both this solution and @GMc's solution construct the read a subset of rows on the driver and create an RDD from it.

Answer (score 4):

You could read a subset of your input data into a dataSet of String.
The CSV method allows you to pass this as a parameter.

Here is a simple example (I'll leave reading the sample of rows from the input file to you):

```
val data = List("1,2,hello", "2,3,what's up?")
val csvRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").csv(csvRDD.toDS)
df.schema
```

When run in spark-shell, the final line from the above prints (I reformatted it for readability):

```
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = 
    StructType(
      StructField(_c0,IntegerType,true),
      StructField(_c1,IntegerType,true),
      StructField(_c2,StringType,true)
    )
```

Which is the correct Schema for my limited input data set.

Comment: Yeah, that's smart! Similar to the out-of-band solutions in that I'm not leveraging distributed reading from the executor, but rather doing a local read on the driver. But it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks. If reading from, say HDFS, you could still read data from the cluster and use the limit method when creating the csvRDD dataset. Is that what you mean by distributed reading from the executor?

Comment: @Jedi, if this has helped you, could you please accept it as the answer.