# how can I optimize schema inference on a remote file for CSV with Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I have a remote file in S3 (or other) and I need the schema of the file.
I did not find an option to sample the data as for JSON (`e.g. read.option("samplingRation", 0.25)`).

Is there a way to optimize the reading of the schema?

Spark reads the entire CSV file over the network before returning the inferred schema. For large files this can take quite a long time.

`.option("samplingRatio", samplingRatioVal)` does not work on csv

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
    * infer schema for a remote csv file by reading a sample of the file and infering on that.
    * the spark-infer-schema behavior by default reads the entire dataset once!
    * for large remote files this is not desired. (e.g. inferring schema on a 3GB file across oceans takes a while)
    * speedup is achieved by only reading the first `schemaSampleSize` rows
    *
    * @param fileLocation
    * @param schemaSampleSize rows to be taken into consideration for infering the Schema
    * @param headerOption
    * @param delimiterOption
    * @return
    */
  def inferSchemaFromSample(sparkSession: SparkSession, fileLocation: String, schemaSampleSize: Int, headerOption: Boolean, delimiterOption: String): StructType = {
    val dataFrameReader: DataFrameReader = sparkSession.read
    val dataSample: Array[String] = dataFrameReader.textFile(fileLocation).head(schemaSampleSize)
    val firstLine = dataSample.head

    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val ds: Dataset[String] = sparkSession.createDataset(dataSample)

    val extraOptions = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String]
    extraOptions += ("inferSchema" -> "true")
    extraOptions += ("header" -> headerOption.toString)
    extraOptions += ("delimiter" -> delimiterOption)

    val csvOptions: CSVOptions = new CSVOptions(extraOptions.toMap, sparkSession.sessionState.conf.sessionLocalTimeZone)
    val schema: StructType = TextInputCSVDataSource.inferFromDataset(sparkSession, ds, Some(firstLine), csvOptions)

    schema
  }
```

eg.

schemaSampleSize = 10000

delimiterOption = ','